# Access violation writing location 0xCCCCCCC?

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2012

When I try to push_back any element, it gives me the error "Unhandled exception at 0.x00D644AB in Project.exe: 0xC000005: Access violation writing location 0xCCCCCCC." I've tried looking for a solution, but can't seem to find one that relates to me. Thanks tons.

```
    SDAL(){
        T* list = new T(50);
        size1=50;
        numberOfElements=0;
    }

    void push_back( const T& element ) {
        numberOfElements++;
        if(numberOfElements>=size1-1){
            expandArray();
        }
        list[numberOfElements-1]=element;
    }
```

The error points to "list[numberOfElements-1]=element;" when i debug it.

The full code is here:

```
template <typename T>
 class SDAL {
 private:
     int size1;
     int numberOfElements;
     T* list;

 public:
    SDAL(){
        T* list = new T[50];
        size1=50;
        numberOfElements=0;
    }
    SDAL(int x){
        T* list = new T[x];
        size1=x;
        numberOfElements=0;
    }
    void expandArray(){
        int tmpSize = size1;
        size1=(int)((double)size1*1.5);
        T* tmp = new T[size1];
        for(int x=0; x<tmpSize; x++){
            tmp[x]=list[x];
        }
        list=tmp;
    }
    void push_back( const T& element ) {
        numberOfElements++;
        if(numberOfElements>=size1-1){
            expandArray();
        }
        list[numberOfElements-1]=element;
    }
```

Comment: A perfect use case for `std::vector`.

Comment: When the access violation exception happens you can debug and view the instruction that caused the exception. Can you debug your program?

Comment: Why did you decide to omit large parts of the code? You could easily have shown a complete program. Why `size1-1`?

Comment: At what point do you allocate memory for `list` **as an array**?

Comment: You know, leaking the memory which should back the elements in your container in the ctor is not useful.

Comment: Sorry, the code is much bigger than this and I didn't think the rest is relevant so I didn't want to make you guys read more than necessary

Answer (score 4):

Visual C++ fills uninitialized memory with 0xcccccccc in debug-mode, because that's more likely to be caught. Thus trapping on access to 0xcccccccc should be quite a useful hint.

Your error is simple:

You are allocating memory in the ctor to store your containers elements, but:

- You only allocate enough for one element.
- You assign it to a temporary instead of to the member.

Using that thus still uninitialized pointer will naturally trap on your first access.

Comment: To elaborate on the assignment to temporary part: Doing `T* list = new T[50];` in the constructor is declaring a local variable named `list` which hides the member variable of the same name. Instead it should be `list = new T[50];` so that the member is used.

Answer (score 1):

To allocate an array, make sure you use square brackets:

```
    T* list = new T[50];
                   ^  ^
```

Your current code allocates a single `T` (and initializes it to 50).

Comment: Thanks, I tried that, but I'm still getting the same error

Comment: @user3272701: At a guess, look for the same error in other parts of the code.

Comment: @user3272701 Please don't ask us to debug your code, code that we can't see. We can answer the questions that you ask. If you ask bad questions, that's on you. This is the problem with the code in the question. If you have a bug in your code, please debug it. Please also try to listen to the answers when you ask. What's the point of asking and then ignoring the answer. You made the same mistake multiple times. It's not enough to just fix one of your mistakes. If you make the mistake again and again, your have to fix it each time. Why don't you read your own code. And this answer.

Comment: I'm reading all the advice you guys are giving, but the problem is still there, sorry if it looks like I'm not trying, but I've been on this for a few hours.